# How do I resolve "sourceSelector is not a function" in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm working in a React project and I'm trying to dispatch an action to make a get request. However I'm receiving 'TypeError: sourceSelector is not a function'.

Here is my code from ViewDocument.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import AccountFlowHeader from 'components/Header/AccountFlowHeader';
import { LoadingModal } from 'components/Modals';

import { policiesSelector } from '../Policies/Policies.redux';
import { logOutAction } from '../Login/Login.actions';

import BasePage from '../BasePage';
import { getPolicyStatus } from './PolicyViewDocument.actions';

class PolicyViewDocument extends BasePage {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showLoaderForPolicyDocument: false,
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
    super.componentDidMount();
    const { currentPolicy: { contractNum } } = this.props;
    this.setState({ showLoaderForPolicyDocument: true }, () => {
      this.props.getPolicyStatus(contractNum, () => {
        this.setState({ showLoaderForPolicyDocument: false });
      }, (code) => {
        if (code === 'C002') {
          console.log(code);
        } else {
          this.setState({
            showLoaderForPolicyDocument: false,
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getPolicyStatus,
};

export default withRouter(connect(policiesSelector, mapDispatchToProps, { logOutAction })(PolicyViewDocument));
```

And here is my code from Actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import urls from 'constants/urls';
import { getErrorCode } from 'utils/common';
import globals from 'constants/globals';

export const getPolicyStatus = (contractNum, scb, fcb) => {
  axios({
    url: urls.getPolicyStatus(contractNum),
    method: 'get',
    timeout: globals.timeout,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200 && !response.data.errors) {
        if (scb) scb(response.data);
      } else if (fcb) fcb(getErrorCode(response));
    })
    .catch((e) => { if (fcb) fcb(getErrorCode(e.response)); });
};
```

I'm sure it has something to do with how I'm using mapDispatchToProps however I haven't been able to resolve.

Comment: At the very least, at which line does the error happen?

Comment: Its occurring the Connect library for redux. connectAdvanced.js

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `super.componentDidMount`?? I guess you have used `sourceSelector` in your parent component, because I am not seeing any `sourceSelector` thing in your share code snippets.

Try removing `super.componentDidMount` from here.

Comment: Its actually coming from connectAdvanced.js. The connect library for Redux.

Comment: "policiesSelector", is this a function? as connect's first parameter which is mapStateToProps should be a function.

Comment: Ok, I removed policiesSelector as its not needed for this view. Here is that line now. Do you see anywhere I should make changes here?
`export default withRouter(connect(mapDispatchToProps, { logOutAction })(PolicyViewDocument));`

Comment: You must pass undefined or null as first argument then in place of mapStateToProps.

Comment: Third parameter should also be the function, but you are passing object there. Third parameter is mergeProps.
Follow this link: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect